# One p:poll stop the other?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm newest with primefaces. What I'm trying to do is to fill a h:outputText, but i have to use p:poll because I make a request and I have to wait for response and it can take some time until I get the answer.

```
<h:form id="form1">
   <p:poll widgetVar="headerPoll" interval="3" listener="#{bean.refreshHeader()}" update="form1"  />  
</h:form>
<h:form id="bodyForm"> 
   <p:commandButton actionListener = "#{bean.loadBody}" ajax="false" value="load body"  /> <br/><br/>
   <h:outputText id="bodyText" escape="false" value="#{bean.body}"   /> 
   <p:poll widgetVar="bodyPoll" interval="3" listener="#{bean.refreshBody()}" update="bodyText"  />
</h:form>
```

The associated bean:

```
 public void refreshHeader()
    {
        if(header != null)
        {
            RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            reqCtx.execute("headerPoll.stop();");
        }
    }

    public void refreshBody()
    {
        if(body != null)
        {
            RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            reqCtx.execute("bodyPoll.stop();");
        }
    }
```

The problem is at `refreshHeader()` function. When `headerPoll.stop()` get executed it stop the first and the second poll. I need to stop only one.

How can I stop only one of these polls ?

Comment: Which version of PF are you using ?

Comment: You have to note that you have a button which is ajax="false" that would affect your polls ....I have tested your code and it's working fine for me.

Comment: You can "unrender"(make rendered attribute `false`) on stop behaviour.

Comment: primefaces 5.0. I use render and work. I've also set ajax to true at commandButton. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

See you have set `interval=3` in both the polling that's why both the functions get called parallely. Try running polling at different time. Hope it will work :)

Comment: The execution of first function stop second poll. In this case _refreshBody()_ never get called. I've tried to change interval but nothing. Sorry :(